# How is the a Fermi surface different from a Fermi sphere?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, metals

How is a Fermi surface (a surface in reciprocal space separating the occupied electron states from unoccupied states at $T=0$) different from a Fermi sphere? Is Fermi sphere a special case of Fermi surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a Fermi sphere is just a special case (and almost always an idealization). The shape of a ``real'' Fermi surface is discussed in Mermin and Ashcroft, but a quick search on [google image](https://www.google.com/search?q=fermi%20surface&client=ubuntu&hs=mum&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOouKF14_eAhULCxoKHaoNBVQQ_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=1085) gives examples of what they really look like in solids.

Answer (score 1):

When the system is perfectly periodic, the Fermi surface is the level set associated to the Fermi energy $E_{\mathrm{F}}$, i. e. consisting of those Bloch momenta $k$ for which $E_n(k) = E_{\mathrm{F}}$ holds for some band index $n$. Note that this definition also works for insulators where the Fermi energy lies in a spectral gap. But then the Fermi energy is the empty set.

For homogeneous systems where the Hamiltonian is just the free Hamiltonian $H = \frac{1}{2m} \bigl (- \mathrm{i} \hbar \nabla \bigr )^2$, then the only energy band is $E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} k^2$ so that the Fermi surface is a perfect sphere.